# Split/unmerge merged cells in notebook file

Tags: functions, notebooks, cells

I have merged cells in a `Notebook` file.

Is there a way to split such a merged cell group back to single cells, in each of them being one command?

Comment: Try right-clicking somewhere in the cell and than select *Divide Cell* or left-click somewhere in the cell and than press Shift+Ctrl+D.

Comment: It is important not to mark the cell (not like one would do when merging).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this code after your merged cell and evaluate, it should print below all expressions separately.

I don't know how solid it is but worth a try:

```
Composition[
  Scan[NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], Cell[#, "Input"]] &, #] &,
  Thread,
  DeleteCases[#, "\[IndentingNewLine]" | "\n", {2}] &,
  First,
  NotebookRead

] @ PreviousCell[]
```

Comment: Nice method.  You might take style e.g. `"Input"` from the original Cell style instead to make this more robust.