# How to print output within an input block?

Tags: output-formatting, output, printing, input

I would like to print data within a signle input block in a way something like this:

```
In[153]:= a = 5;
          Print[a];
          (*expected output (5) here*)
          b = 3;
```

Is there any way to achive this effect?

Comment: You can't. output cells are separate from input cells. All output from an input cell go to a separate cell after the input cell.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Does this answer your question? [Cell splitting in mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164065/cell-splitting-in-mathematica)

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.